# what is the best way of doing conditional selection in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am new to sql, sorry this might be pretty basic.

I have table called T1

```
T1
ID   Group Entity Percentage  Long_Term   Short_Term
1    AAA    BBB      99%      Long    
2    CCC    DDD      99%                  Short
3    EEE             99%      Long
4           FFF      99%                  Short
```

Insert into T2

```
ID   Name   Classification   Percentage  Term
```

if Group and Entity both are both not null, then just select Entity.
so desired T2 will be:

```
ID   Name   Classification   Percentage  Term
1  BBB      Entity              99       Long
2  DDD      Entity              99       Short
3  EEE      Group               99       Long
4  FFF      Entity              99       Short
```

How to select from T1 and insert into T2 like T2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECODE` function will be of help here. We check if `Entity` IS NULL, if so, take the value from the `Group` column. We do the same with `classification`, but here we provide literal values as the result. I see you also wanted the same thing in for the `Term` column?

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id NUMBER,
  group_val VARCHAR2(3),
  entity VARCHAR2(3),
  percentage VARCHAR2(4),
  long_term VARCHAR2(20),
  short_term VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, 'AAA', 'BBB', '99%', 'Long', NULL);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2, 'CCC', 'DDD', '99%', NULL, 'Short');
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3, 'EEE', NULL, '99%', 'Long', NULL);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4, NULL, 'FFF', '99%', NULL, 'Short');

COMMIT;

CREATE TABLE t2 AS
  SELECT
      id,
      DECODE(entity, NULL, group_val, entity) AS name,
      DECODE(entity, NULL, 'Group', 'Entity') AS classification,
      percentage,
      DECODE(long_term, NULL, short_term, long_term) AS term
  FROM
    t1;

SELECT * FROM t2;
```

```
        ID NAME CLASSIFICATION PERCENTAGE TERM               
---------- ---- -------------- ---------- --------------------
         1 BBB  Entity         99%        Long                 
         2 DDD  Entity         99%        Short                
         3 EEE  Group          99%        Long                 
         4 FFF  Entity         99%        Short
```

If you already have the `t2` table, then:

```
INSERT INTO t2
  SELECT
      id,
      DECODE(entity, NULL, group_val, entity) AS name,
      DECODE(entity, NULL, 'Group', 'Entity') AS classification,
      percentage,
      DECODE(long_term, NULL, short_term, long_term) AS term
  FROM
    t1;
```

Check at <kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ebb3/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You do this with COALESCE (or NVL) and a CASE clause:

```
select 
  id, 
  coalesce(groupid, entity) as name,
  case when entity is not null then 'Entity' else 'Group' end as classification,
  percentage, 
  coalesce(long_term, short_term) as term
from  t1;
```

BTW: Don't call your column GROUP. GROUP is an SQL word.